# How do I use a network connection after I have created it in network manager GUI?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have used the network management GUI (located on the system status bar at the top of the screen).

I have created a new connection for connecting to my Wifi access point - I  selected options and filled out fields for the config that I want.
Then clicked the <kbd>save</kbd> button.
To me it seems as though the config is now "remembered" - but not used.

My question is:

how do I then connect to a wifi access point using that connection?

Comment: Trying clicking on it from the drop down menu which would appear when you click the network icon on the menu bar

Comment: Other than the permanent menu items I only see a list of the Wifi networks themselves - i.e. their SSID's. I dont see any connections that I have created

Answer (score 0):

If you are already connected to a wifi network then try disconnecting from it first. Or if you have created a wifi network from your computer itself then you've to turn it off. After you've disconnected, select your newly created network. If the configuration parameters are right and the you are in range of the wifi network then your new network will be connected.